# clear the textbox after redirect to a download page

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

i have 2 pages. main.aspx and download.aspx
page_load at download.aspx is to download a file
textbox and download button at main.aspx
-no function at page_load
-button redirect to download.aspx
-textbox cannot be left blank.

after i filled the textbox and press the button, the page remain at main.aspx and file is downloaded from download.aspx.
now the problem is, how can i clear the textbox after i press the download button?

I tried:

1. `this.Textbox1.Text = "";` before and after the redirect.
2. `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "document.getElementById('Textbox1').value =''", true);` before and after the redirect
3. `Response.Redirect("main.aspx);` after `Response.Redirect("download.aspx");`
4. `onclientclick = "validation()"`

function validation() {
        document.getElementById('TextBox1').value= "";
    }

remember i have the validation, so 4. cannot work.

```
5. 

    OnClientClick ="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';"/>

          Response.Redirect(”download.aspx”,false);
        Textbox1.Text="";

6. Textbox1.EnableViewState = false;
```

7.button clicked, redirect to main2.aspx, pageload at main2.aspx redirect to download.aspx. but after i clicked the button at main.aspx, the file is downloaded, but the page is still remains at main.aspx.

none of the method above is working, what else can i try? and what is the problem? why the textbox cannot set to blank?

main.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.TextBox1.Text = "";
   Response.Redirect("download.aspx");
   this.TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

download.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string reportPath = "C:\\form.pdf";

   Response.ContentType = "appplication/pdf";
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=form.pdf");
   Response.TransmitFile(reportPath);
   Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Any clearing event you have will only work on postback. So only after the page loads / reloads. You need to use Javascript to clear it client side

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript to clear the textbox value

Comment: Please improve your answer on how you would do it using javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I think,you can use the get method to download.
the button's onClientClick code:

```
function doGet(){
var txt=document.getElementById('<%=this.TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
window.open ('download.aspx?file='+txt);
document.getElementById('<%=this.TextBox1.ClientID %>').value='';
}
```

and in the download.aspx.cs

you can get the value from the main.aspx,like

```
string file=this.Request.QueryString["file"];
```

Don't use the ReDirect method to request the download page.

Comment: problem still remains, however i have tried another method, have a look at method 7.